# How to convert html to base64 and save an image on a server with php?

Tags: javascript, php, base64, blob, html2canvas

I have a json file like this:

```
{"user":{"email":"user@test.com"},
 "screenshot":{"blobFile":"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\">...</html>"}}
```

and I want to take a screenshot, using XMLHttpRequest sending data a PHP file.

In PHP file getting request like:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$htmlStr = json_encode($data["screenshot"]["blobFile"]); // <!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\">...
```

so far everything is ok but how to convert this string to the image file and save a server?

I've tried [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) in PHP file but not fire.

any ideas?

Comment: are you trying to do this on server side only? https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Comment: html2canvas is a js-library. How did you try to use that in PHP? Since javascript is run in the brower, html2canvas uses the browser to generate the image. PHP doesn't have a browser and aren't able to parse HTML on it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It's headless browser, which allows to interact with web pages many ways including making screenshots. It will require some time to understand how to work with it, but it definitely will get a result. Although, PhantomJS sometimes is a headache if your page is quite complicated structured, written using some frameworks like ReactJS, AngularJS, etc.

What it does it renders HTML page with styles including scripts serverside. If you save not HTML string but exact URL with COOKIE and SESSION data and then reconstruct conditions which user had in an opened page when you did a screenshot, it'll do a job.

See example here [Screen Capture on PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)